# Control's OnExit eats up mouseup event for new control when showing another window

Tags: delphi, delphi-7

I found this question on [Experts-Exchange](http://www.experts-exchange.com/Programming/Languages/Pascal/Delphi/Q_20654804.html).

> Control's OnExit eats up mouseup event for new control when showing
>   another window
>
> The problem can be replicated easily.
>
> place 3 tedits on a form. write a showmessage('exit') in edit1's
>   onexit event run the program give edit1 focus use the mouse to give
>   edit3 focus, click ok to the showmessage observe how you can't write
>   anything in edit3 now, until you click with the mouse somewhere on the
>   form ! give edit2 focus, then use to the mouse to give edit3 focus
>   observe how you can type what you want in edit3 now  !
>
> So far I've established that the problem lies in the fact that edit3
>   doesn't receive a mouseup-message when the old controls onExit event
>   displays a window of any kind, i've tried it as well with showing a
>   form of my own in the onExit event, same result. In fact, windows is
>   under the impression that the mouse is held down over edit3 after
>   you've clicked Ok to the showmessage
>
> I guess it's a bug in Delphi/Windows but how to work around it ? I
>   know i can force a WM_LBUTTONUP on edit3's onMouseDown event (since
>   its the last event called in the process) but that's more than
>   tedious, and not always applicable

I am trying to do something similiar:

In the onexit event I show a warningbox and then want to proceed
as normal - moving the focus to where the user in fact clicked.
Is that possible?

Comment: Don't provide modal warnings in an OnExit event handler. Limit the warning to visual aids. If you need to show a modal warning, do it when submitting the form (clicking OK).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Once again `PostMessage` to the rescue! Defer your dialog just a little bit longer so that Windows can finish its focus change. Post yourself a message instead of showing the dialog directly:

```
const
  WM_SHOWMYDIALOG = WM_APP + 321;

TForm1 = class(TForm)
  Edit1: TEdit;
  Edit2: TEdit;
  procedure Edit1Exit(Sender: TObject);
private
  procedure WMSHOWMYDIALOG(var Message: TMessage); message WM_SHOWMYDIALOG;
end;

procedure TForm1.Edit1Exit(Sender: TObject);
begin
  PostMessage(Self.Handle, WM_SHOWMYDIALOG, 0, 0);
end;

procedure TForm1.WMSHOWMYDIALOG(var Message: TMessage);
begin
  ShowMessage('Nice one');
end;
```

And everything is fine :)

Answer (score 4):

I'm not so sure that the reason of the behavior is an eaten mouse message. Anyway, either that's the case or not, when you activate a window in an `OnExit` event of a control, what you're doing is, changing the focus while the focus is changing. That's because, the window is activated before `WM_SETFOCUS` for the newly focused control returns. This is discouraged, the below quote is from 'Best practices' section of '[Win32 Activation and Focus](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/jfoscoding/archive/2006/08/02/686141.aspx)', a blog entry on MSDN:

> Avoid manually changing focus when getting and/or losing focus.  This
>   usually proves to be error prone.

The fact that the controls are disabled during focus transfer due to the modal nature of the activated window certainly would not help. If you really must do this, an approach like [Heinrich's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7079960/controls-onexit-eats-up-mouseup-event-for-new-control-when-showing-another-windo/7080420#7080420) would at least delay the launch of the window till the focus transfer completes.

Answer (score 2):

> In the onexit event I show a warningbox and then want to proceed as normal - moving the focus to where the user in fact clicked. Is that possible?

Yes, `(Screen.)ActiveControl` will always point to `Edit3`: before and after the call to ShowMessage:

```
procedure TForm1.Edit1Exit(Sender: TObject);
begin
  ShowMessage('Exit');
  PostMessage(ActiveControl.Handle, WM_LBUTTONUP, 0, 0);
end;
```

**But this is just for completeness sake to your question! And it certainly is no tip nor advice!** See Sertac's answer for the reason.