# Delphi onshow main form / modal form

Tags: forms, delphi, modal-dialog

I have a project which has a main form and some other forms. 
When the app loads it needs to carry out some tasks and show the results in a modal form on top of the main form.
The problem I have is that if I put the call to the function to do the tasks / creates and Show the modal form in the main forms onshow event the modal form appears but the main form does not until the modal form is closed, which is what I would expect to happen. To counter this I have added a timer to the main form and start it on the main forms onshow event the timer calls the function to do the tasks / create and show the modal form. So now the main form appears before the modal form.

However I cannot see this being the best solution and was wondering if anyone could offer a better one.

I am using Delphi 7

Colin

Comment: use PostMessage. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7094873/visibility-of-form-in-delphi

Comment: sorry for the off-topic by why does this question shows "blurred" in the main questions list?

Comment: @kobik: AFAIK questions show dimmed when they have a tag you ignore, and when they have a negative vote score that is beyond a certain limit. BTW questions about the way SO works are better asked on the meta site (see link in the main navigation).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

One commonly used option is to post yourself a message in the form's `OnShow`. Like this:

```
const
  WM_SHOWMYOTHERFORM = WM_USER + 0;

type
  TMyMainForm = class(TForm)
    procedure FormShow(Sender: TObject);
  protected
    procedure WMShowMyOtherForm(var Message: TMessage); message WM_SHOWMYOTHERFORM;
  end;

...


procedure TMyMainForm.FormShow(Sender: TObject);
begin
  PostMessage(Handle, WM_SHOWMYOTHERFORM, 0, 0);
end;

procedure TMyMainForm.WMShowMyOtherForm(var Message: TMessage);
begin
  inherited;
  with TMyOtherForm.Create(nil) do begin
    try
      ShowModal;
    finally
      Free;
    end;
  end;
end;
```

Comment: While this is the correct idea for a solution, the implementation of it shown is not so good. :) Use the custom message, and implement a handler for that specific message instead of replacing the entire WndProc. Just declare your custom message before the form's type declaration, and add `procedure UMShowMyOtherForm(var Message: TMessage); message UM_SHOWMYOTHERFORM;`. Then the only thing that interrupts the normal flow of `WndProc` is your custom message.

Comment: @Ken True that. I'm used to handling message IDs that are allocated at runtime

Comment: This is how those before me handled this, so I keep doing it this way because it works. Some technical details would be nice, if you have them.

Comment: @MarcusAdams Details on which aspect? PostMessage or message handlers?

Comment: @David, what's the magic behind how this works? Is it because the message to draw the MainForm is ahead of the custom message on the queue, both of which get processed after the OnShow?

Comment: @MarcusAdams The `OnShow` event handler is called before the call to `ShowWindow` is made. So it would perhaps be better named as `OnJustBeforeShow`. For the main form showing for the first time, this all happens as the final act before starting the main thread message pump (Application.Run). Posting a message to the queue allows us to make sure that the call to `ShowWindow` is made before the queued message gets processed. However, researching this leads me to an even better solution......

Comment: @Ken Thanks, but it's my other answer that actually nails this one in my view!!

Comment: I don't like the other one because other things might be using the CM_SHOWINGCHANGE; I prefer to save it for things like components or embedded dialogs (within components), and use specific custom ones for things like this. (Although I *do* properly use `WM_APP + ANumber` for my message identifiers as the API says you should. :))

Comment: @Ken It doesn't matter if anything else is using `CM_SHOWINGCHANGE`. All other users will be unaffected because you call inherited.

Comment: I'm aware of that, but I still prefer this method. Probably just a personal bias. ;)

Comment: @Ken What I dislike about this is a concern that the posted message goes to the back of the queue and other queued messages get processed first. So some form of UI might get to the main form before the modal form shows. Getting both forms up before the main message loop starts avoids that pitfall.

Comment: What I dislike about the other is that it can fire repeated times, and you need the additional boolean to track whether your related action has been completed. By posting a message at the end of the constructor, it only gets sent once (unless the form is freed and created again) and therefore there's no need for the additional tracking logic/variable. Like I said, probably just a personal preference.

Comment: @Ken The same argument is true for `OnShow`. Granted you probably know that you show the main form once only. But that's not so for some apps. Sometimes you hide the main form and leave an icon in the notification area. Of course, if we had multi-cast events then the problem could be solved in a much more elegant way. Oh to be on .net!

Comment: I didn't say `OnShow`; I said `constructor`. :) The form's constructor is only called once. :)

Comment: @Ken OK, see that now. I suppose you'd better hope nothing pumps the queue before the main form gets shown then. Don't want any rogue ProcessMessages. I still think this answer is poor and the other one is the right way. Taking chances on when the queue is pumped seems risky.

Comment: I don't use `ProcessMessages`. **Ever.** So there can't be one. I don't use third-party components that use `ProcessMessages` either. And I don't use third-party components without source, so they can't sneak by. :)

Answer (score 2):

Why dont you use the `MainForm OnActivate` event like so?

```
procedure TMyMainForm.FormActivate(Sender: TObject);
begin
  //Only execute this event once ...
  OnActivate := nil;

  //and then using the code David Heffernan offered ...
  with TMyOtherForm.Create(nil) do begin
    try
      ShowModal;
    finally
      Free;
    end;
end;
```

Setting the event to nil will ensure that this code is only run once, at startup.

Answer (score 0):

The `OnShow` event is fired immediately before the call to the Windows API function `ShowWindow` is made. It is this call to `ShowWindow` that actually results in the window appearing on the screen.

So you ideally need something to run immediately after the call to `ShowWindow`. It turns out that the VCL code that drives all this is inside a `TCustomForm` message handler for `CM_SHOWINGCHANGED`. That message handler fires the `OnShow` event and then calls `ShowWindow`. So an excellent solution is to show your modal form immediately after the handler for `CM_SHOWINGCHANGED` runs. Like this:

```
type
  TMyMainForm = class(TForm)
  private
    FMyOtherFormHasBeenShown: Boolean;
  protected
    procedure CMShowingChanged(var Message: TMessage); message CM_SHOWINGCHANGED;
  end;

.....

procedure TMyMainForm.CMShowingChanged(var Message: TMessage);
begin
  inherited;
  if Showing and not FMyOtherFormHasBeenShown then begin
    FMyOtherFormHasBeenShown := True;
    with TMyOtherForm.Create(nil) do begin
      try
        ShowModal;
      finally
        Free;
      end;
    end;
  end;
end;
```